# Offline instant messaging

Tags: mobile, signalr, offlineapps

I'm developing an instant messaging app. I'm going to use SignalR for pushing messages to clients. How should I handle offline devices to get the latest messages? I have two solutions in mind:

1. When server wants to send messages to device, it does not care if the device is online or not. It just sends data with SignalR, so if device is offline user does not get the message. When device is online again, it sends the latest ID of the record in device's SQLite to the server. Then server sends messages with ID greater than that to the client.
2. When server wants to send messages to device, it first checks if the device is online or offline. If it is online it sends the message using SignalR. If the device is offline it sends push notifications - using GCM for Android or APNS for iOS - to device. Then when device is online it checks push notifications and updates messages in SQLite.

Which solution is better?

Comment: @Biffen- thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it depends on your needs. Do your clients expect to be notified of things when they're not using the application? I expect this would be the case for most general-purpose instant messaging applications (like Skype and friends).

Alternatively, users may prefer to not be notified when they don't have the application running. I would personally suggest that you do the easier option first- just option 1- and only add notifications if needed. [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) is a great tool for this sort of thing.